# Adding JTextField corrupts key bindings

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, key-bindings

I have a problem with the creation of my panel and setting properly key bindings. When I add JTextField to my JFrame, my key binding(s) do stop working. So, for example here is the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing my problem - if you comment lines containing JTextField pressing `p` will work as desired. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Example{
    Example(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()); 
        panel.setFocusable(true); 
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        KeyboardInput keyboard = new KeyboardInput(panel);

        // adding JTextField corrupts key bindings
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
        textField.setFont(textField.getFont().deriveFont(15));
        textField.setText("text");
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setFocusable(true);
        textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        textField.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Example();
    }
}

class KeyboardInput{
    KeyboardInput(JPanel panel){
        InputMap inMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        ActionMap actMap = panel.getActionMap(); 
        inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("P"), "pauseGame");
        actMap.put("pauseGame", new pauseAction());
    }

    class pauseAction extends AbstractAction {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("PAUSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved…

`textField.setFocusable(true);` should be changed to `textField.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: If you just want to display text then use a JLabel.